# For which field does the Eisenstein-criterion work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

*I want to proof/show that a polynomial is reducible or irreducible in $\Bbb Q[X]$ or $\Bbb Z[X]$.*

*For $p=3$ the Eisenstein-Criterion works, but I'm not sure for which field.
All coefficients of the polynomials are in $\Bbb Z$.*

*Wolfram Alpha says there are 5 zeros, two complex and three rationals.*

*But I thought it was irreducible in $\Bbb Q$, because of Eisenstein.*

Could someone maybe explain me it ?

P.S. Does the first coefficient necessarily need to be monic ?

$x^5-36x^4+6x^3+30x^2+24$

Comment: Yes, if a polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$, it remains irreducible in $\mathbb Q[X]$.  This is a consequence of Gauss's lemma.  Your original post fails to give the (degree five?) polynomial, so it's hard to guess where the disconnect occurs.

Comment: Which polynomial do you mean?

Comment: @bellcircle: this one

Comment: @hardmath: I thought, that it's irreducible in $\Bbb Z$, but reducible in $\Bbb Q$

Comment: So, yes this is irreducible by [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) with $p=3$.  I don't think Wolfram Alpha is trying to tell you it has three rational roots, but instead that there are three real roots (and is showing you decimal approximations).

Comment: @hardmath: thanks !